# Why does FF3 say "Permission denied to get property HTMLDivElement.tagName"?

Tags: javascript, dojo, firefox-3, inlineeditbox

When I run this through FireFox 3:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/dojo-1.2.3-src/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/dojo-1.2.3-src/dojo/dijit.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.require("dojo.parser");
dojo.require("dijit.InlineEditBox");
dojo.require("dijit.form.TextBox");

function myHandler(idOfBox, value) {
 alert("Edited value from "+idOfBox+" is now "+value);
}
</script>

<span id="editable" style="font-size:larger;" dojoType="dijit.InlineEditBox"
onChange="myHandler(this.id,arguments[0])">
<input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" value="dijit.InlineEditBox">
</span>
```

and click on the inline editable text, change it, and then click outside of it, FF says this: "Permission denied to get property HTMLDivElement.tagName"

The Firebug debugger breaks at the following line because e.relatedTarget is null:

> try{ e.relatedTarget.tagName; } catch(e2){ return; }

What can I do to find a fix for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem *appears to be* caused by the Firebug extension to Firefox. I say that because when I disable Firebug and use the control, it works normally.

Answer (score 2):

Yah, I tried it myself but it's working for me, at least against the latest code.  (I'm running on FF3/mac.)

The try/catch you mention may be a red-herring as there's already a catch handler setup that ignores any errors.

Comment: +1 Thanks for trying that out! I'm sorry to say I have not understood what's happening there.